# NG0203 - Using a service in a component both declared in the same Library

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library

We have a library that uses an injection token for the API URL.
This is injected into the service like:

```js
constructor(@Inject(UMBRACO_FORM_CONFIG) umbracoConfig: UmbracoFormConfig, private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.umbracoFormsApiUrlBase = umbracoConfig.umbracoFormsApiUrlBase;
}
```

Then the service is injected into the **standalone** component as normal:

```js
constructor(private umbracoService: UmbracoFormService) {}
```

We have provided the token UMBRACO_FORM_CONFIG in the main application but when we try to load the component we get the following error:

```
Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with 'runInInjectionContext'. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203     
at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:731:15)     
at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:744:60)     
at Object._class3_Factory [as useFactory] (core.mjs:89:84)     
at Object.factory (core.mjs:9546:38)     at core.mjs:9447:43     
at runInInjectorProfilerContext (core.mjs:694:9)     
at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:9446:17)     
at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9316:33)     
at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:738:40)     
at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:744:60)     
at resolvePromise (zone.js:1193:31)     
at resolvePromise (zone.js:1147:17)     
at zone.js:1260:17     
at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)     
at core.mjs:27127:55     
at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:27127:36)     
at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)     
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:27437:33)     
at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)     
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:173:47)
```

We have tried:

- Exporting the service from the library and adding it to the providers in the main app
- Adding providers to the standalone component

Neither of these have changed the error we get.

Any ideas on what we can do to resolve this?

Comment: can u add a stackblitz example?

Comment: @MojtabaNejadPoorEsmaeili I tried to reproduce this in a stackblitz and found that it only occurs across different projects.

If I create a workspace with a lib and app this error does not occur.
If I create a lib project and a app project separately then I get this error.

Comment: so can you reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: No I can not as I believe the only option in stackblitz is to run a angular workspace which I know doesn't cause the issue.